# "shell not found" on start of backtrack 5

Tags: linux, backtrack, ksh

I am using backtrack5 in VMware on my system. I was trying to change my default shell to ksh. After executing the 'chsh' command. On restarting the OS, it shows "Cannot execute ksh: no such file or directory", which apparently because of giving a bad path while changing shell.

Because of this I am not able to start the OS, as I have no terminal to interact with (cannot start the GUI). Now I need to restore the previous shell, but I don't have any access to the terminal.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot to a rescue CD, mount the root file system, chroot to set the mounted FS as root and re-run chsh.